# I can understand

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

When some person explains about his behaviour to me, what are the alternate ways of saying that 'I can understand' what he is trying to say?

Comment: How many have you come up with yourself?

Comment: I can understand /I can relate/ I totally understand you

Comment: I get you / I'm with you / I hear you / Of course / Been there

Comment: Just "I understand" on its own works, too.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to show someone that you can understand what they are trying to say such as, **I see, I know what you mean, I bet, I see/take your point, I get you, Oh right - fair enough....etc**